# Which user is started with a process in java in LinuxI?

Tags: java, google-chrome, ubuntu, process, google-chrome-headless

I'm trying to start chrome headless through Java through processBuilder and here's my code :

```
pb = new ProcessBuilder(CHROME_UBUNTU_PATH, "--headless","--enable-logging", "--disable-gpu","--print-to-pdf=" + filePath + ".pdf","file:///" + absolutePath);
pb.start();
```

But chrome wouldn't start cause it's running with the user root :

```
Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported.
```

So I want to know what user is a process is launched with and what should I do in this situation ?

Comment: The process is going to be launched by whatever user is running the java application, unless you explicitly use commands to run the command as a different user.

Comment: Well you gave me the reason, so how do I start the process with another user ?

Comment: Look at GhostCat's answer. You are chasing an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). The answer is not to start the process with another user, but determine if there is actually a need to run the Java application as root (most likely not), and if not, run it as a normal user.

Comment: I appreciate the quick accept ;-) ... just wondering: is there something I could add to also make the answer upvote-worthy?

Comment: Yep, what setup to look into ? cause I tried to start my jboss server with a normal user and the problem still appears

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple: the process that runs this codes and tries to launch chrome is run by the `root` user. And because of that, the new process goes under the same user `root`.

Which is like the very last thing you want to do: you want to run as few jobs as possible with as `root` user.

In other words: the solution is to look into your setup and to ensure that you absolutely do **not** start *any* process as `root` yourself. (maybe there are exceptions where you have to, but again: that should be the absolute exception and only happen when there is no alternative for doing so).

Comment: but why it's launched with the user root ?

Comment: Because the Java process is launched with user root. I can't tell you why **you** (r box) is running that java process as root.